# How do I create a local database inside of Microsoft SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

Forgive me if this question was already asked before.

I just installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014. I want to create a database so I can start building some tables from scratch. All I am getting is the ability to connect to a database. Not create a new database.

Comment: I imagine it's asking you to connect to a Server not a database. Once you connect to the relevant server you can then create a database.

Comment: then how do i create a server? i am a noob at this.

Comment: You create one when you install SQL Server. If you don't have one you'll need to run the SQL Server installation and it will take you through the process of creating a new SQL Server 2014 instance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As per comments, First you need to install an instance of SQL Server if you don't already have one - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143219.aspx

Once this is installed you must connect to this instance (server) and then you can create a database here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms186312.aspx

Comment: i got the answer from this youtube video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_zFM7mzFUg

Answer (score 20):

*Warning!* SQL Server 14 Express, SQL Server Management Studio, and SQL 2014 LocalDB are separate downloads, make sure you actually installed SQL Server and not just the Management Studio!
[SQL Server 14 express with LocalDB download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299)

Youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGFdh_D0lYs) about entire process.
[Writeup](https://www.sqlshack.com/install-microsoft-sql-server-express-localdb/) with pictures about installing SQL Server

**How to select a local server:**

When you are asked to connect to a 'database server' right when you open up SQL Server Management Studio do this:

**1)** Make sure you have Server Type: Database

**2)** Make sure you have Authentication: Windows Authentication (no username & password)

**3)** For the server name field look to the right and select the drop down arrow, click 'browse for more'

**4)** New window pops up 'Browse for Servers', make sure to pick 'Local Servers' tab and under 'Database Engine' you will have the local server you set up during installation of SQL Server 14

**How do I create a local database inside of Microsoft SQL Server 2014?**

**1)** After you have connected to a server, bring up the Object Explorer toolbar under 'View' (Should open by default)

**2)** Now simply right click on 'Databases' and then 'Create new Database' to be taken through the database creation tools!

Comment: Ah! I only downloaded management studio and forgot to install the actual sql server... Thanks for that.

Comment: ^ agreed, that warning was the solution to my problems. Thank you!

Comment: Dammit this is the third program I'm installing now :p If only MS could be clear about these things, instead of pointing to the wrong software...

Answer (score 3):

1: Download MSQL server from below link.
2: During installation it will ask to install SSMS , so install that if not already installed.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Comment: This link no longer resolves to anything meaningful.